# message not shown when page is maximized.just shown when resized

Tags: javascript, html

I have a hidden message that should be shown just when we hit a radiobox.But its showing just when we resize the page in smaller

here s the message and the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $(".whatHappened [type=radio]").change(function () {
                 var selVal = $('input:radio[name=LossType]:checked').val();
                 if (selVal == "Tow_DispatchDisabledVehicle")
                     $('#ersMessage').show();
                 else
                     $('#ersMessage').hide();
             });


        });
     </script>
```

and the message:

```
 <div id="ersMessage" style="display:none">
                        <div class="hideDesktop">
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            error message ........
                        <ul>
                            <li>Call 000000</li>
                            <li>CALL 0000</li>
                        </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I hope its clear

Comment: It's working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/753dqq6y/6/

Comment: great.so it could be something related to css so the message is hidden by another thing?

Comment: Perhaps you can create a minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the issue occur and help you fix it.

Comment: I deleted the div hidedesktop and it worked